# Club the records in the column of same data in different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i need to join the records in different rows with same. like my TESTNAME is same project name in different row i need to club them and display it into one row also the query i used is for this is to make pivot please find the below code

```
select ProjectName,  
ProjectNos,  
isnull([Questionnaire Submission for sripting],'') as c1,  
isnull([Programing of questionnaire and/or ConJoint Design/Email Send out],'') as c2,  
isnull([Quality Check (Desktop and Mobile)],'') as c3,  
isnull([Questionaire link sent to client for review],'') as c4,  
isnull([Hard Launch],'') as c5,  
isnull([Data Collection],'') as c6,  
isnull([Quality Check (Sampling)],'') as c7,  
isnull([Status of sampling process sent to client],'') as c8,  
isnull([Data Exported & Cleansed],'') as c9,  
isnull([Coding of Open Answers],'') as c10,  
isnull([Table Report],'') as c11,  
isnull([PPT Report],'') as c12,  
isnull([Data Analysis],'') as c13,  
isnull([Raw Data Delivery to CDT],'')as c14,  
isnull([Quality Check ( Table Report/Raw Data)],'')as c15,  
isnull([Power Point Quality Check ],'')as c16,  
isnull([Final Presentation Delivery to CDT],'')as c17,  
isnull([Extra Analysis (after presentation)],'')as c18,  
isnull([N-visualize report],'')as c19,  
isnull([Excel Delivery],'') as c20 from tbl_ProjectDetails   
PIVOT   (  
 max(Status_Name) for   
 [Task_assigned] IN   
 ([Questionnaire Submission for sripting],  
 [Programing of questionnaire and/or ConJoint Design/Email Send out],  
 [Quality Check (Desktop and Mobile)],  
 [Questionaire link sent to client for review],  
  [Hard Launch],  
 [Data Collection],  
 [Quality Check (Sampling)],  
 [Status of sampling process sent to client],  
 [Data Exported & Cleansed ],  
 [Coding of Open Answers],  
 [Table Report],[PPT Report],  
 [Data Analysis],  
 [Raw Data Delivery to CDT],  
 [Quality Check ( Table Report/Raw Data)],  
 [Power Point Quality Check ],  
 [Final Presentation Delivery to CDT],  
 [Extra Analysis (after presentation)],  
 [N-visualize report],[Excel Delivery])) as pivottable where flag='0'
```

and its output as below

```
ProjectName ProjectNos                  c1              c2         c3                 c4        
test 123    123456                  Not yet started                                                         
TESTNAME    45612                                       Alert                                                           
testfr      785412                  Missed deadline         
sdsd        adsads                                                Not Applicable                                                        
tyeuir      8948948                 In progress                                                                     
wwew        2324234234                                                                Not yet started                           
TESTNAME    45612                   Missed deadline
```

Comment: Please make the question clear. Give a brief explanation on that you are trying to achieve @user2583182

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select ProjectName,  
ProjectNos,  
isnull([Questionnaire Submission for sripting],'') as c1,  
isnull([Programing of questionnaire and/or ConJoint Design/Email Send out],'') as c2,  
isnull([Quality Check (Desktop and Mobile)],'') as c3,  
isnull([Questionaire link sent to client for review],'') as c4,
isnull([Hard Launch],'') as c5,  
isnull([Data Collection],'') as c6,  
isnull([Quality Check (Sampling)],'') as c7,  
isnull([Status of sampling process sent to client],'') as c8,  
isnull([Data Exported & Cleansed],'') as c9,  
isnull([Coding of Open Answers],'') as c10,  
isnull([Table Report],'') as c11,  
isnull([PPT Report],'') as c12,  
isnull([Data Analysis],'') as c13,  
isnull([Raw Data Delivery to CDT],'')as c14,  
isnull([Quality Check ( Table Report/Raw Data)],'')as c15,  
isnull([Power Point Quality Check ],'')as c16,  
isnull([Final Presentation Delivery to CDT],'')as c17,  
isnull([Extra Analysis (after presentation)],'')as c18,  
isnull([N-visualize report],'')as c19,  
isnull([Excel Delivery],'') as c20 
from (
    select ProjectName,  
    ProjectNos,
    Status_Name,
    [Task_assigned] 
    from tbl_ProjectDetails
    where flag='0') as t
PIVOT   ( 
 max(Status_Name) for   
 [Task_assigned] IN   
 ([Questionnaire Submission for sripting],  
 [Programing of questionnaire and/or ConJoint Design/Email Send out],  
 [Quality Check (Desktop and Mobile)],  
 [Questionaire link sent to client for review],  
  [Hard Launch],  
 [Data Collection],  
 [Quality Check (Sampling)],  
 [Status of sampling process sent to client],  
 [Data Exported & Cleansed ],  
 [Coding of Open Answers],  
 [Table Report],[PPT Report],  
 [Data Analysis],  
 [Raw Data Delivery to CDT],  
 [Quality Check ( Table Report/Raw Data)],  
 [Power Point Quality Check ],  
 [Final Presentation Delivery to CDT],  
 [Extra Analysis (after presentation)],  
 [N-visualize report],[Excel Delivery])) as pivottable
```

Result

```
ProjectName ProjectNos  c1              c2      c3              c4  ...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sdsd        adsads                              Not Applicable                                                                  
test 123    123456      Not yet started                                                                         
testfr      785412      Missed deadline                                                                         
TESTNAME    45612       Missed deadline Alert                                                                       
tyeuir      8948948     In progress                                                                         
wwew    2324234234                                              Not yet started
```

Comment: hey andrey doesnt work for me. im still getting the same output

Comment: ok, can you please share the table structure (create table script) and some sample data (several INSERT statements) in order to provide ability to execute your query?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_ProjectDetails](
 [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [ProjectName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
 [ProjectNos] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
 [Startdate] [datetime] NULL,
 [enddate] [datetime] NULL,
 [Analyst] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [Qualitycheck] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [flag] [bit] NULL,
 [Task_assigned] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [Status_Name] [varchar](max) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]